# Building a map from another table with a composite primary key

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following tables in my DB:

```
statement:
id | created_date | message
```

and

```
statement_configuration
id | name | currency
```

and

```
statement_balances
statement_id | statement_configuration_id | balance
```

Where the `statement_balances` table has a composite primary key on `statement_id` and `statement_configuration_id`.

My `Statement` entity looks like this:

```
public class Statement implements Serializable {

  @Id
  private long id;

  @Column
  private String message

  //I'm not sure of which annotations I need here
  @OneToMany
  private Map<Long, StatementBalance> statementBalancesByConfigId;
  ....
}
```

The `StatementBalances` entity looks like this:

```
public class Statement implements Serializable {

  @Id
  private long statmentId;

  @Id
  private long statementConfigurationId;

  @Column
  private long balance;
  ....
}
```

My goal is to build a Map of type `Map<Long, StatementBalances>` inside my `Statement` entity. The map will map the `statement_configuration_id` to a `balance`; allowing me to get all the `StatementBalance`s that are linked to this `Statement` (keyed by `statement_configuration_id`).

Is it possible to build this map using JPA annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. An example solution:

```java
@Entity
public class Statement implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private long id;

    private String message;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "statementId")
    @MapKey(name = "statementConfigurationId")
    private Map<Long, StatementBalances> statementBalancesByConfigId;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "statement_configuration")
public class StatementConfiguration implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "statementConfigurationId")
    private Collection<StatementBalances> statementBalances;

    private String name;
    private String currency;
}
```

The `StatementBalancesId` composite primary key class and `StatementBalances` entity class allow modeling a ternary association by creating of two bidirectional relationships between them:

```java
public class StatementBalancesId implements Serializable {
    long statementId;
    long statementConfigurationId;

    // requires no-arg constructor, equals, hashCode
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "statement_balances")
@IdClass(StatementBalancesId.class)
public class StatementBalances implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="statement_configuration_id")
    private StatementConfiguration statementConfigurationId;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="statement_id")
    private Statement statementId;

    @Column
    private long balance;
}
```

The database tables created this way are identical as those in the question.